NG8004: No pipe found with name 'uppercase'. [plugin angular-compiler]
my components name is heroes
heroes.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrl: './heroes.component.css'
})
export class HeroesComponent {
  hero : Hero={
    id:1,
    name :'Windstorm'
  };

}

and
heroes.component.html
<h2>{{hero.name| uppercase }} Details</h2>

compilar showing error like this-
X [ERROR] NG8004: No pipe found with name 'uppercase'. [plugin angular-compiler]
src/app/heroes/heroes.component.html:1:17:
  1 │ <h2>{{hero.name| uppercase }} Details</h2>
    ╵                  ~~~~~~~~~

Error occurs in the template of component HeroesComponent.
src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts:8:15:
  8 │   templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


you have a typo uppercaase should be uppercase! Ensure you import the pipe UpperCasePipe or the module CommonModule to the imports of the standalone component!

So was there a typo in your code or not?

Also - is it angular or angularJs (v1 vs v(any))

@Justinas There was a typo also there was an import missing, I added answer for clarity!

@NarenMurali I have improved the typo and also included the import common module ...
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';                                               but still showing same error

@ambuj151
But the import is not added to the imports array, please check my answer once.

@Justinas now there is no typo ,,and its angular only

In order to use uppercase pipe we need to import the module/pipe for the standalone component to use this functionality
importing module, which contains uppercase pipe!
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrl: './heroes.component.css'
})
export class HeroesComponent {
...

importing just the pipe (UpperCasePipe)
import {UpperCasePipe} from '@angular/common';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [UpperCasePipe],
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrl: './heroes.component.css'
})
export class HeroesComponent {
...

the usage for this pipe will be below on the HTML
{{ value_expression | uppercase }}

